# How do I bypass a @ symbol in my password when opening a URL from a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to open a URL in browser without a login window prompt as below:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

ECHO This is a batch file
ECHO Staring URL ...

:BEGIN
Start http://Admin:12!3@dmin@localhost:1234
EXIT
```

I expect to log in to the URL without the login prompt dialogue box, but since the password is not validated due to <kbd>@</kbd> symbol, I get the login prompt.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>@</kbd> is considered a special character in a URL as it has a special role. You would therefore need to URL encode it, i.e. **`%40`**. However as `%` is a special character in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), you'd also need to escape any instance of one with another, i.e. **`%%40`**.

```bat
@Start http://Admin:12!3%%40dmin@localhost:1234
```

The main 'special' characters to URL encode would be, **<kbd>$</kbd>**, **<kbd>&</kbd>**, **<kbd>+</kbd>**, **<kbd>,</kbd>**, **<kbd>/</kbd>**, **<kbd>:</kbd>**, **<kbd>;</kbd>**, **<kbd>=</kbd>**, **<kbd>?</kbd>**, **<kbd>@</kbd>**,  , **<kbd>"</kbd>**, **<kbd><</kbd>**, **<kbd>></kbd>**, **<kbd>#</kbd>** and **<kbd>%</kbd>**

However, you should also consider these characters too, **<kbd>{</kbd>**, **<kbd>}</kbd>**, **<kbd>|</kbd>**, **<kbd>\</kbd>**, **<kbd>^</kbd>**, **<kbd>~</kbd>**, **<kbd>[</kbd>**, **<kbd>]</kbd>** and **<kbd>`</kbd>**